# Extract data off mongodb database per each day from past week

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `nodeJS` and I have a MongoDB table, in which there are documents with my self-created field `timestamp`. Example for this field in document: `timestamp: "24-09-2020 08:25:55.301"`. I'd like to extract data off the table, of documents counter for each day. Meaning I'd like to get how many documents were in each past week day (using the `timestamp` field).

The perfect data I'd like to get from the query is an array of size `7`, And each array item describes how many documents found for this date.

How can I do it?

Comment: You can write an aggregation query and get the desired result.  You may want to take a look at the `$match` and `group` stages.

Comment: Try searching the net using the string "_MongoDB aggregation grouping by date_" - you will find some posts similar to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** store date/time values as string, use always proper `Date` object.

One solution is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         timestamp: {
            $dateFromString: {
               dateString: "$timestamp", format: "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%L", timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: moment.tz('Europe/Zurich').subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day').toDate() } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: { $year: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" } },
               month: { $month: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" } },
               day: { $dayOfMonth: { date: "$timestamp", timezone: "Europe/Zurich" } },
               timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
            }
         },
         documents: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   },
   { $project: { timestamp: "$_id", documents: 1, _id: 0 } }
])
```

Comment: Suggest use `$addFields` for backward compatibility instead of `$set`

Comment: Is it solution for the case the timestamp is a string? Could you edit it for the case the timestamp is a date?

Comment: If field `timestamp` is already a `Date` object, simply skip the first stage (`$set`) which converts the string into a Date

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, I started my Mongo carrier with Mongo 4.2, so I am already used to `$set`

Comment: I did `npm i moment` then `const moment = required('moment')`. Why does it say `TypeError: moment.tz is not a function.`?

Comment: You also have to download the time zone extension: [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) - unless you work with UTC times. Or use just `moment().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day').toDate()` for local time.

Comment: `{ $gte: { $subtract: [new Date(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000] } }` may also work - but it gives **exactly** 7 days less, i.e. no truncate to midnight.

Comment: It gives me in the result also `timestamp` which is unneccessary for me. How can I emit this field?

Comment: `{ $project: { timestamp: 0, documents: 1, _id: 0 } }`

Comment: gives me `MongoError: Bad projection specification, cannot include fields or add computed fields during an exclusion projection: { timestamp: 0, documents: 1, _id: 0 }.`

Comment: @ShalviMuqta just do `{ $project: { documents: 1 } }`, you get the above error [`because of this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24949677/7177029)